# How to properly and correctly make up a diagram that will be used in the future?

Tags: html, charts, diagram

I have a chart on the site, it displays referral percentages, I need to make it in HTML. After me with the schedule will work another person, please advise how to do it right, perhaps some ready-made solution?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer that myself. Made on grids, with the ability to control the width of the element and its beginning. Might be helpful to someone

```css
.diagram-referal {
  margin-top: 38px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 1170px;
  
}

.diagram-referal__content {
  padding: 24px 0 0 0;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 85px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 85px 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
}

.diagram-referal__levels {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: (1fr)[3];
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.diagram-referal__row {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background: url("../img/referals/repeat-line.svg") 0 100% repeat-x;
  background-size: 85px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.diagram-referal__element {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[12];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.diagram-referal__level {
  font-family: VisbyCF;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #212121;
  padding: 21px 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.diagram-referal__grid {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #FDA53C;
}

.diagram-referal__grid_red {
  background-color: #F3361A;
}

.diagram-referal__item {
  font-family: VisbyCF;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.diagram-referal__bottom {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[13];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.diagram-referal__date {
  font-family: VisbyCF;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
}
.diagram-referal__date:first-child {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
      grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-referals__diagram diagram-referal">
                                <div class="diagram-referal__wrapper">
                                    <div class="diagram-referal__body">
                                        <div class="diagram-referal__content">
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__levels">
                                                <div class="diagram-referal__level">1 Level</div>
                                                <div class="diagram-referal__level">2 Level</div>
                                                <div class="diagram-referal__level">3 Level</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__row">
                                                <div class="diagram-referal__element">
                                                    <div style="grid-column-start: 2; width: 460%"   class="diagram-referal__grid">
                                                        <div class="diagram-referal__item"><span>$</span>12345</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="diagram-referal__element">
                                                    <div style="grid-column-start: 5; width: 320%"   class="diagram-referal__grid diagram-referal__grid_red">
                                                        <div class="diagram-referal__item"><span>$</span>12345</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="diagram-referal__element">
                                                    <div style="grid-column-start: 4; width: 300%;"  class="diagram-referal__grid">
                                                        <div class="diagram-referal__item"><span>$</span>12345</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="diagram-referal__bottom">
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">10 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">11 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">12 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">13 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">14 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">15 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">16 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">17 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">18 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">19 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">20 Oct</div>
                                            <div class="diagram-referal__date">21 Oct</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
```